# First page after titlepage (with titlepage extension) with too large bottom margin in Quarto for pdf

Tags: pdf, latex, rstudio, margins, quarto

I am working with Quarto to create a pdf document from rstudio. I use the quarto_titlepages  extension to create a title page, which is followed by a text of several pages. The first one of these pages is shown with a very large bottom margin, which is probably a heritage of the title page. However, this only happens with the bottom margin and not with the top one.

I tried re-stablishing the margins in the pdf format section with margin-left, margin-right, margin-bottom and margin-top. Then I tried the same approach but using geometry instead. None of the two options worked.
Here is the code with margin-top and so on.

```
---
title: "Here we have a title, not too long"  
author:  "First Author and Second Author"  
date: last-modified  
date-format: "d-MMMM-YYYY"  
lang: "es"  
format:  
  titlepage-pdf:  
    documentclass: scrreport  
    titlepage: plain  
    titlepage-geometry:  
      - top=90mm  
      - bottom=60mm 
      - right=30mm  
      - left=30mm  
    titlepage-logo: "images/anyimages.png"  
    titlepage-bg-image: "images/anyimage2.png"  
    titlepage-theme:   
      elements: ["\\titleblock", "\\logoblock", "\\authorblock", "(some additional information)"      ]  
      page-fontfamily: "Helvetica Neue"  
      page-align: center  
      title-fontsize:  30  
      title-align: center  
      title-fontstyle: []  
      title-space-after: 3cm  
      author-fontsize: 16  
      author-style: plain  
      logo-align: center  
      logo-size: 4cm  
      logo-space-after: 4cm  
      bg-image-location: "ULCorner"  
      bg-image-size: 21cm   
  pdf:  
    # Fonts  
    mainfont: Helvetica Neue  
    fontsize: 12pt  
    papersize: A4  
    margin-top: 25mm  
    margin-bottom: 25mm  
    margin-left: 25mm  
    margin-right: 25mm  
    toc: true  
    toc-depth: 2  
    toc-title: Táboa de contidos  
editor: visual  
---

## Introdución  


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nec condimentum eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed congue tellus at vehicula interdum. Vivamus dapibus ante vitae rhoncus posuere. Ut ut ipsum nisl. Nullam luctus viverra augue id feugiat. Fusce sollicitudin sed massa eget blandit. Pellentesque tempus lacinia metus, nec facilisis massa varius eget. Proin in felis sed arcu faucibus scelerisque. Sed hendrerit tortor nisl, sed mattis lectus luctus at. Nulla et lorem ac est venenatis posuere. Vivamus eget vehicula purus, sit amet mollis nunc. Phasellus pellentesque nisi eu porttitor egestas. Aliquam a aliquam lectus, eu iaculis mauris.


Suspendisse eu gravida orci. Suspendisse vehicula sagittis libero quis lobortis. Suspendisse potenti. Sed imperdiet ligula eu tellus tincidunt rutrum. Vivamus vel nibh vel lacus efficitur tempus. Maecenas sit amet erat at sapien blandit congue. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vivamus vel nunc hendrerit, venenatis sapien nec, commodo libero. Ut vehicula porta euismod. Vivamus eu dolor neque. Mauris a dui faucibus, elementum dui nec, condimentum nibh.


Etiam aliquam, arcu eget ornare elementum, leo magna sollicitudin augue, vel dapibus lectus nisi ac ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec semper lacus mauris, ac maximus lectus volutpat nec. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed interdum, velit non sollicitudin volutpat, purus tellus aliquam lacus, et scelerisque ex nisi et ex. Vivamus porta purus ac mauris placerat, venenatis suscipit augue accumsan. Cras consequat dapibus efficitur.


Phasellus diam felis, condimentum vitae diam nec, tincidunt bibendum elit. Donec condimentum, orci in euismod vestibulum, sapien massa maximus lectus, vel interdum magna magna non lectus. Integer vitae nunc nec urna feugiat venenatis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent sapien velit, molestie nec molestie vel, sodales at mauris. Maecenas accumsan malesuada ipsum eget pellentesque. Nam aliquet leo sit amet felis facilisis facilisis. Vivamus aliquam iaculis eros, non bibendum elit convallis ut. Quisque ut varius arcu. Vivamus pellentesque nisi vitae nisi vulputate, quis dapibus est efficitur. Aenean eget ipsum in lorem aliquet efficitur aliquet a est. In sit amet vehicula eros. Donec dui nulla, ultrices ut nisi non, ornare viverra ante.


Proin facilisis sit amet velit placerat porttitor. In congue risus id tempus congue. Cras rutrum justo at ultricies faucibus. Ut sed turpis nec nulla malesuada feugiat sed eu risus. In mattis eu tellus sit amet commodo. Nam molestie vulputate ullamcorper. Curabitur egestas ligula ut urna blandit faucibus.
```

And this is what I get in the two pages after the title page

[image]

**UPDATE**
I solved it partially, by following samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz's advice (using \restoregeometry). Then I realized that it was not only geometry, but I was also losing all other formats detailed under *pdf:*. To solve it I erased the *pdf:* line; that is, all pdf formats should directly go under "titlepage-pdf:". But, again, by doing so, the first page appeard with a large bottom margin, even when using \restoregeometry.

This is my code now:

```
---
title: "Here we have a title"
author:  "Author 1 with surname & Author 2 with surname"
date: last-modified
date-format: "d-MMMM-YYYY"
lang: "es"
format:
  titlepage-pdf:
    documentclass: scrreport
    titlepage: plain
    titlepage-geometry:
      - top=90mm
      - bottom=60mm
      - right=30mm
      - left=30mm
    titlepage-logo: "images/circularNegro.png"
    titlepage-bg-image: "images/OsTres.png"
    titlepage-theme: 
      elements: ["\\titleblock", "\\logoblock", "\\authorblock", "(some additional text)"      ]
      page-fontfamily: "Helvetica Neue"
      page-align: center
      title-fontsize:  30
      title-align: center
      title-fontstyle: []
      title-space-after: 3cm
      author-fontsize: 16
      author-style: plain
      logo-align: center
      logo-size: 4cm
      logo-space-after: 4cm
      bg-image-location: "ULCorner"
      bg-image-size: 21cm 
    # Fonts
    mainfont: Helvetica Neue
    fontsize: 12pt
    papersize: A4
    margin-top: 25mm
    margin-bottom: 25mm
    margin-left: 25mm
    margin-right: 25mm
    toc: true
    toc-depth: 2
    toc-title: Táboa de contidos
editor: visual
---

\restoregeometry

## Introdución

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nec condimentum eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed congue tellus at vehicula interdum. Vivamus dapibus ante vitae rhoncus posuere. Ut ut ipsum nisl. Nullam luctus viverra augue id feugiat. Fusce sollicitudin sed massa eget blandit. Pellentesque tempus lacinia metus, nec facilisis massa varius eget. Proin in felis sed arcu faucibus scelerisque. Sed hendrerit tortor nisl, sed mattis lectus luctus at. Nulla et lorem ac est venenatis posuere. Vivamus eget vehicula purus, sit amet mollis nunc. Phasellus pellentesque nisi eu porttitor egestas. Aliquam a aliquam lectus, eu iaculis mauris.

Suspendisse eu gravida orci. Suspendisse vehicula sagittis libero quis lobortis. Suspendisse potenti. Sed imperdiet ligula eu tellus tincidunt rutrum. Vivamus vel nibh vel lacus efficitur tempus. Maecenas sit amet erat at sapien blandit congue. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vivamus vel nunc hendrerit, venenatis sapien nec, commodo libero. Ut vehicula porta euismod. Vivamus eu dolor neque. Mauris a dui faucibus, elementum dui nec, condimentum nibh.

Etiam aliquam, arcu eget ornare elementum, leo magna sollicitudin augue, vel dapibus lectus nisi ac ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec semper lacus mauris, ac maximus lectus volutpat nec. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed interdum, velit non sollicitudin volutpat, purus tellus aliquam lacus, et scelerisque ex nisi et ex. Vivamus porta purus ac mauris placerat, venenatis suscipit augue accumsan. Cras consequat dapibus efficitur.

Phasellus diam felis, condimentum vitae diam nec, tincidunt bibendum elit. Donec condimentum, orci in euismod vestibulum, sapien massa maximus lectus, vel interdum magna magna non lectus. Integer vitae nunc nec urna feugiat venenatis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent sapien velit, molestie nec molestie vel, sodales at mauris. Maecenas accumsan malesuada ipsum eget pellentesque. Nam aliquet leo sit amet felis facilisis facilisis. Vivamus aliquam iaculis eros, non bibendum elit convallis ut. Quisque ut varius arcu. Vivamus pellentesque nisi vitae nisi vulputate, quis dapibus est efficitur. Aenean eget ipsum in lorem aliquet efficitur aliquet a est. In sit amet vehicula eros. Donec dui nulla, ultrices ut nisi non, ornare viverra ante.

Proin facilisis sit amet velit placerat porttitor. In congue risus id tempus congue. Cras rutrum justo at ultricies faucibus. Ut sed turpis nec nulla malesuada feugiat sed eu risus. In mattis eu tellus sit amet commodo. Nam molestie vulputate ullamcorper. Curabitur egestas ligula ut urna blandit faucibus.
```

And this is what I get:
[image]

Comment: You should probably report this bug somewhere...

Comment: I did not even suspect it was a bug...I'm really new to Quarto and know nothing on latex. But I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that quarto and/or the titlepage extension issues `\restoregeometry` at the wrong place. If one looks at the intermediate .tex file, one will see code like this:

```
...
\clearpage
\restoregeometry
%%% TITLE PAGE END
\end{titlepage}
...
```

However `\restoregeometry` needs to be used after the title page is closed (it would also make more sense to have the `\clearpage` after the title page...)

You can work around it my manually adding one more `\restoregeometry` before your text:

```
---
title: "Here we have a title, not too long"  
author:  "First Author and Second Author"  
date: last-modified  
date-format: "d-MMMM-YYYY"  
lang: "es"  
format:  
  titlepage-pdf:  
    documentclass: scrreport  
    titlepage: plain  
    titlepage-geometry:  
      - top=90mm  
      - bottom=60mm 
      - right=30mm  
      - left=30mm  
    titlepage-logo: "example-image-duck"  
    titlepage-bg-image: "example-image-duck"  
    titlepage-theme:   
      elements: ["\\titleblock", "\\logoblock", "\\authorblock", "(some additional information)"      ]  
      page-fontfamily: "Helvetica Neue"  
      page-align: center  
      title-fontsize:  30  
      title-align: center  
      title-fontstyle: []  
      title-space-after: 3cm  
      author-fontsize: 16  
      author-style: plain  
      logo-align: center  
      logo-size: 4cm  
      logo-space-after: 4cm  
      bg-image-location: "ULCorner"  
      bg-image-size: 21cm   
editor: visual  
---

\restoregeometry

## Introdución  


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nec condimentum eros. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed congue tellus at vehicula interdum. Vivamus dapibus ante vitae rhoncus posuere. Ut ut ipsum nisl. Nullam luctus viverra augue id feugiat. Fusce sollicitudin sed massa eget blandit. Pellentesque tempus lacinia metus, nec facilisis massa varius eget. Proin in felis sed arcu faucibus scelerisque. Sed hendrerit tortor nisl, sed mattis lectus luctus at. Nulla et lorem ac est venenatis posuere. Vivamus eget vehicula purus, sit amet mollis nunc. Phasellus pellentesque nisi eu porttitor egestas. Aliquam a aliquam lectus, eu iaculis mauris.


Suspendisse eu gravida orci. Suspendisse vehicula sagittis libero quis lobortis. Suspendisse potenti. Sed imperdiet ligula eu tellus tincidunt rutrum. Vivamus vel nibh vel lacus efficitur tempus. Maecenas sit amet erat at sapien blandit congue. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vivamus vel nunc hendrerit, venenatis sapien nec, commodo libero. Ut vehicula porta euismod. Vivamus eu dolor neque. Mauris a dui faucibus, elementum dui nec, condimentum nibh.


Etiam aliquam, arcu eget ornare elementum, leo magna sollicitudin augue, vel dapibus lectus nisi ac ipsum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec semper lacus mauris, ac maximus lectus volutpat nec. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed interdum, velit non sollicitudin volutpat, purus tellus aliquam lacus, et scelerisque ex nisi et ex. Vivamus porta purus ac mauris placerat, venenatis suscipit augue accumsan. Cras consequat dapibus efficitur.


Phasellus diam felis, condimentum vitae diam nec, tincidunt bibendum elit. Donec condimentum, orci in euismod vestibulum, sapien massa maximus lectus, vel interdum magna magna non lectus. Integer vitae nunc nec urna feugiat venenatis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent sapien velit, molestie nec molestie vel, sodales at mauris. Maecenas accumsan malesuada ipsum eget pellentesque. Nam aliquet leo sit amet felis facilisis facilisis. Vivamus aliquam iaculis eros, non bibendum elit convallis ut. Quisque ut varius arcu. Vivamus pellentesque nisi vitae nisi vulputate, quis dapibus est efficitur. Aenean eget ipsum in lorem aliquet efficitur aliquet a est. In sit amet vehicula eros. Donec dui nulla, ultrices ut nisi non, ornare viverra ante.


Proin facilisis sit amet velit placerat porttitor. In congue risus id tempus congue. Cras rutrum justo at ultricies faucibus. Ut sed turpis nec nulla malesuada feugiat sed eu risus. In mattis eu tellus sit amet commodo. Nam molestie vulputate ullamcorper. Curabitur egestas ligula ut urna blandit faucibus.
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect!! It worked smoothly.